# Ionic zip is giving different byte array each time

Tags: c#

I am using Ionic zip library to zip and code snippet looks like this.

```
 byte[] b = null;

 using (MemoryStream stream1 = new MemoryStream())
 {
     zip.Save(stream1);
     b = stream1.ToArray();
 }

 return Convert.ToBase64String(b);
```

I am calling this code multiple times and embedding string value into XML as `[CDATA]` and serving that as a response to a web service call. But every time string value inside `[CDATA]` is getting changed for the same file. If we unzip it then expected file is there always. What's wrong with this string and `[CDATA]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing's wrong necessarily.  The zip format stores metadata as well as the compressed file contents, so probably you are seeing the results of a timestamp (file creation time?) in the stream, which would make the zip package different every time, even if the file bytes are the same.